# How to detect if browser is offline in 2018?

Tags: javascript, browser, offline, offline-browsing

There used to exist [offline.js](https://github.com/hubspot/offline) for detection of a connection, but that project is no longer maintained.  Also, the browser's 'navigator.onLine' property is notoriously [unreliable](https://jonbellah.com/articles/online-offline-events/).

What is the best/most up-to-date method to use to actively detect the browser's online state, compatible with modern browsers including mobile device browsers, that can raise various events when the online status changes?  Do I need to write this myself, or is that reinventing the wheel?

Note that *nobody* in my userbase is going to be changing the "Work Offline" setting in the browser in order to go online/offline.  Instead, they will be unplugging network cables, disconnecting from wifi networks, driving to locations where no signals are available, etc.

My thought was to simply set up a timeout to repeatedly make AJAX calls to a URL on my server, and simply set an 'online' variable to true/false as well as call online/offline callback functions based on error/success of the AJAX call.  Is that the recommended way?

Comment: perhaps try with [online/offline events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine/Online_and_offline_events)? though it may be the same as navigator.onLine, which should be reliable in modern browsers according to the [MDN link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine/Online_and_offline_events)?

Comment: @MalteR I think these events also aren't guaranteed to offer a true online/offline status... It sounds more like nobody has bothered to develop a new library for this after the offline.js library was left to die.  I wonder why?  Am I missing something?

Comment: @MalteR The events don't work either...

Comment: Did you find anything Ryan? I wrote one myself; with a 'connection service' making constant pings and keeping track of an 'online' property (and behavior subject), and a http interceptor which tries to set the status based on any request to my backend. This is really flaky, but this is how I interpret the browser to be offline, or rather, the backend as unreachable: `(err.status === 0 && err.ok === false && err.name === 'HttpErrorResponse') || err.status === 504`, but I'm pretty sure this is browser/library-dependent.

Comment: @VincentSels Yes that's what did too.  Just hit a web api and check for errors.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
`var wentOffline, wentOnline;
 function handleConnectionChange(event){
    if(event.type == "offline"){
        console.log("You lost connection.");
        wentOffline = new Date(event.timeStamp);
    }
    if(event.type == "online"){
        console.log("You are now back online.");
        wentOnline = new Date(event.timeStamp);
        console.log("You were offline for " + (wentOnline — wentOffline) / 1000 + "seconds.");
    }
}
window.addEventListener('online', handleConnectionChange);
window.addEventListener('offline', handleConnectionChange);`
```

Check the post: https://medium.com/@MateMarschalko/online-and-offline-events-with-javascript-d424bec8f43

Answer (score 0):

I worked on a similar implementation and this was my solution using setInterval and fetch API.
There will be 2 functions, first function will run for every 30 seconds checking internet connection.
A flag variable is set to true which will control the function execution.
In case of disconnection, the second function will be invoked to call fetch API for every 5 seconds. If successfully connected, the flag is set to true so the first function can be executed again for every 30 seconds and the interval is cleared.

```
doesConnectionExist: function() {
setInterval(function () {
if(flag === true){
let randomNum = Math.round(Math.random() * 10000);
let url = "test.js?rand=";
const response = fetch(url + randomNum)
                .then(function () {
                    clearInterval(interval);
                })
                .catch(function () {
                     console.log("You are currently offline.");
                     interval = setInterval(function () { checkForConnectivity(); }, 5000);
                });
}
}, 30000);
}

checkConnectivity: function() {
flag = false;
let randomNum = Math.round(Math.random() * 10000);
let url = "test.js?rand=";
const response = fetch(url + randomNum)
                .then(function () {
                    console.log("Your Internet connection was restored.");
                     clearInterval(interval);
                     flag = true;
})
.catch(function () {
                    return null;
                });
};
```

Comment: I like the idea of polling faster when the connection is down, so you will detect the reconnect quicker.

Comment: You can try calling a local js file instead of an external website and the response time would be be quicker and in my case, it returned within few ms. I have updated the code as well.

Answer (score -1):

simply use

```
navigator.onLine
```

see the browser support https://caniuse.com/#feat=online-status

Comment: I'm not sure why you are saying it is not working anymore, this is a well accepted feature, see the browser support

Comment: If you tested it you would see that it’s not working

Comment: just tested in chrome Version 69.0.3497.100

Comment: How did you test it by turning on and off the wifi or by the DevTools?, in the DevTool it will work but not if you're actually turn on/off your connection

Comment: oh, I understand your problem, this will not trigger anything which means if you need to constantly monitor the state of your connection you need to have this inside a interval and give around 10 second delay. 

and then console out the value, I did disableing the wifi directly not by dev tool

Comment: I tested it with different laptops/users with the same Chrome browser version (on Ubuntu) and for some reason it works for some laptops and doesn't work with others.